# Is it worth it to push back about time reporting deadline?

Tags: manager, time

I work as a subcontractor for a company; Really almost all employees at this org are contractors through one of a handful of subcontracting firms.

A while ago, there was a bit of an organizational change, and there's now a new system we are entering time into as a result of it...

Anyways, it used to be that I'd submit time by monday end of day. That's very common, made perfect sense.

The last couple months since this change, this new guy has been on my arse every monday morning, 9 AM sharp, to enter my timesheets. Even sending passive aggressive messages and a bunch of ' ??????????? ' messages. It's really been getting on my nerves, as I have a daily 'agile standup' / micromanagement meeting, so what I'm beginning my monday with, is putting together notes on my status for various things, so i can be prepared for this meeting. Not a priority for me to enter time the first thing monday. Really, I'd normally shoot to have it entered by 11.

So usually in the middle of this meeting this guy will be hounding me, and I'll let him know, I'm entering it right now as I can, but i'm stuck in a meeting, it'll be done soon. Really, consistently, I'm getting it done by 10 or 11 every monday, and I've seen many payroll systems... That should be great. I really haven't understood the level of hounding the members of my team have been getting on this.

So now, the sunday after christmas, a few minutes after midnight going into monday, I see an email pop up on my phone.... "i don't see any hours entered!", remarking that this person needs to see more timely entry into the new year and to make it a priority.

The issue I have is... I really think this is unreasonable. I feel like writing a blunt email response more or less saying, I think you're going to be continually disappointed if you're not able to accept timesheets entered on mondays. For one thing, the week doesn't end friday. It end on saturday/sunday in our system, and we're on call / could spend hours on the weekend.

And so the question on my mind, is really... Would they be willing to fire someone over this? It hasn't been insinuated, but if not, I want to illustrate how silly this is and respond back.

For context, I am very definitively leaving the company in March, anyways (Retiring very very early!). I just feel like pushing back on something that seems very stupid.

Obviously, I ***could*** just enter the time on friday afternoons when I leave for the day or before then. But I don't feel like it. I think it's reasonable to do it monday, and I am in a position that I know would take them 2+ months to fill if it went vacant... It seems like a silly thing to suddenly quarrel about, on their end. And the impact of it seems trivial... For me, I'm paid corp to corp through an LLC... by invoice... So my pay is actually a solid 1-2 months in arrears - so it makes no difference to me whatsoever.

At other contract positions, I've seen pay go out weekly, and I've seen if time doesn't get submitted on time, because payroll runs tuesday/wednesday, if you miss the deadline, it rolls out on the next week. But again... that's a trivial thing. I don't understand the harassment behind it.

Comment: I'm honestly struggling to understand your motivation here: you have a bunch of nuanced answers on this site where it's pretty clear that you understand that a professional working environment isn't always best handled with the equivalent of a sledgehammer - but now you're proposing bringing the equivalent of a wrecking ball. Is there something about filling in a timesheet which makes this such a hot topic for you?

Comment: When I've worked with companies who have a contract with any US military department, there was a contractual requirement to have hours in by the end of each day - so they could get the invoices out. If that didn't happen, sometimes the hours would not be able to get paid. You're not the only pawn in the game.

Comment: They made clear that the timesheet takes priority over other tasks. Maybe you can make an argument otherwise, but with 3 months left, why? If the issue is perhaps the guy emailing you being disrespectful in some way... same response. 3 months and you'll never hear from him again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We had something similar on a monthly base, if the last day of the month happened to be on a weekend you had to finish it by Friday which - as you mentioned - could cause issues when you had to do on call duty.

So what do you do in this situation? Communicate! Ask the guys that set up the deadlines how to handle the situation, specifically about the on-call issues. Just a friendly email showing you are interested in a constructive solution.

They replied and said to just put it on the next weekend without on call duty. They are happy because the month can be closed on time and you are happy because you have all your time reported. Problem solved.

Answer (score 7):

"Obviously, I could just enter the time on Friday afternoons when I leave for the day or before then." - really just do this.

It is not worth to enter an argument (or leave a job) over something so trivial as timesheets. On either of sides. The way you portray the whole situation right now makes you look unreasonable as well.

Comment: That's fair; it just has been bothering me that myself and other members of the team are being pressured over this when they have other things to do, over something that's very reasonable for them to be doing. It's an annoying practice that I know will continue if no one pushes back on it... and there's no reason that it needs to be this way. I did end up writing a response back outlining why I would prefer to do it monday, and why, and they responded that in reality monday before 11 would be fine.

Comment: Just for me, I look at things like this and I think... this is something that actively would make this a crummier workplace for someone else, needlessly. We already have an extreme issue with employee turnover

Comment: It is good to hear that you have discussed this issue and received clarification that it is okay for you to submit your timesheets on Monday. It still perplexes me how this is even an issue. But...  Since you say there is high turnover at your company, my guess is that there are more underlying issues...

Answer (score 5):

> Obviously, I could just enter the time on friday afternoons when I leave for the day or before then. But I don't feel like it.

Excuse me? I must have missed the part where you said you *own* the company. You are a paid subcontractor, aren't you. If they want timesheets by the end of the week before you leave, you do that. Anything else is highly unprofessional. If there is a problem or question with entering time for saturdays, you ask that question. What you don't get to do is to decide for yourself when to do the work they have given you. If you want that, you will have to quit your job and found your own company.

Comment: was going to quote this for the same reason.  No one cares what you geel like doing.  I have had customers expect time entry for *Friday prior to end of day Friday*.

Comment: This has never been stated previously, nor is it in any of our policies. It seems to me one specific person is on some weird sort of trip. Also, being a contractor works two ways - you have an agreement. That agreement only states timesheets need to be entered timely, which they are. & it's not my manager or anyone above him that is pressing this, it's some unrelated person entirely. My manager specifically would rather I be getting actual work done on fridays and submitting it monday. They've got this other person that approves timesheets that's not involved with the actual work at all.

Comment: Well, if they approve your timesheets, one could argue they are more important than anybody else in that company for the purpose of getting your hours billed.

Comment: Do you have a contradictory statement from your manager? Then definetely ask about it.

Comment: @schizoid04 - If the person isn’t responsible for submitting or approving your time, then ignore that person’s request provided your manager approves.  However, that’s important information, you failed to provide in your question